# tf.gradients return all zero vector when called on a tf.gradients result

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient

I have the following code snippet:

```
interpolates = alpha*real_data + ((1-alpha)*fake_data)
disc_interpolates = Discriminator(interpolates)
gradients = tf.gradients(disc_interpolates, [interpolates])[0]
second_grad = tf.gradients(gradients[0], [interpolates])[0]

def Discriminator(inputs):
    output = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, 3, 32, 32])

    output = lib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D('Discriminator.1', 3, DIM, 5, output, stride=2)
    output = LeakyReLU(output)

    output = lib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D('Discriminator.2', DIM, 2*DIM, 5, output, stride=2)
    output = LeakyReLU(output)

    output = lib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D('Discriminator.3', 2*DIM, 4*DIM, 5, output, stride=2)
    output = LeakyReLU(output)

    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, 4*4*4*DIM])
    output = lib.ops.linear.Linear('Discriminator.Output', 4*4*4*DIM, 1, output)

    return tf.reshape(output, [-1])
```

Where `Discriminator` corresponds to a neural network. The first call to `tf.gradients` is working correctly and I get back non-zero slope values in the gradients variable. However, whenever I try to find the second derivative by applying `tf.gradients` to the gradients variable, my result is always a vector of zeroes. I don't expect this to be the case because it shouldn't be perfectly linear, am I using `tf.gradients` incorrectly?

Comment: I have a similar problem with yours, the code of mine returns all zero vectors with the first tf.gradient (gradient of interpolates).Not from the first iteration, but after several iterations.